# Import only the customer from magento 1.9 to Magento 2.2

Tags: customer, importexport

I am creating a new site with Magento 2.2  I need to import only the customer from an old site that is running on Magento 1.9. Any option can be import customer details using .csv file.Please help.

Comment: So you can export from Magento 1 and import it into Magento 2. You can also use Magento Data Migration Tool if you face any errors in the above step